How to add the workspace (not project) directory to a PDSOE propath
We store some support files that are not part of the projects in the eclipse workspace directory.
I need to add that workspace directory to the propath because the application uses search and file-info to locate those files.
Add external directory adds the physical location of the workspace, but I need a variable that is valid if the workspace is in a different location.
How can I achieve this ?
Add workspace directory only allows adding project directories, not the actual workspace directory

It's also not listed as one of the standard paths

Also tried adding
    <propathentry env="all" kind="folder" path="@{ROOT}\..\.." platform="All"/>

or
    <propathentry env="all" kind="folder" path="\oecommon\..\.." platform="All"/>


I am not sure if this is usable for your case.
For the run configuration we use the Eclipse working directory as ABL working directory by specifying:
${workspace_loc:/ui}/..
Variable workspace_loc is provided by Eclipse, ui is a project.
Since the ABL working directory is now the same as the Eclipse working directory, it can be accessed by adding . to the run configuration propath.

I found a solution that works for us, it may not be suitable for everybody.
The propath I need to get the workspace directory in, is the oecommon propath that is used by our launch configs.
The start in directory for those launch configs refers to another project, so I could not use Stefan Drissen's solution.
Steps

Set oecommon project workdir to ${workspace_loc} variable


Add @{WORK} to the propath. If the entry is missing the UI does not allow to add this, but you add the line below by editing .propath file using a text editor.


<propathentry env="all" includeTooling="false" kind="dir" path="@{WORK}" platform="All"/>


